# Node not using local timezone on Debian Jenny

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime, timezone, debian

-`Current default time zone: 'US/Pacific-New'`
-Local time and UTC all look good.
-`$date` gives PDT just fine.

but `new Date` in Node still gives UTC time?
`new Date().getTimezoneOffset()` correctly gives `420` though

I thought Node used local time for `new Date` operations just like the browsers, but I keep getting `2016-10-20T05:07:45.341Z` which is UTC time?

(node ver 6.7.0)

Comment: What do you mean by "gives UTC time" exactly? Do you mean when you convert the `Date()` to a string? Please show a sample value, and what you expected instead.

Comment: console.log and command line?

Comment: Right. Just to be clear, you *only* care about the string representation of a `Date`, right? A `Date` object doesn't have a time zone - you can format it in whatever time zone you want, but it's just a number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch. Personally for server logs, I'd *prefer* that to be in UTC - but you can always format it in a different time zone if you want.

Comment: Oh seriously?! I always thought it stored it in a weird string format and to get the mil-sec version you had to call `.getTime()`

Comment: You do not want to use `US/Pacific-New` that was created [for some messed up stuff in 1989 that never came to be](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/master/pacificnew).  Use `US/Pacific`, or preferably, `America/Los_Angeles`.

Comment: @MattJohnson Oh I just used `dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`, didn't see either so yea, changed now to gmt+7, thanks.

Comment: If you mean `Etc/GMT+7`, that is for UTC-7 fixed.  It won't return to UTC-8 when DST ends in the US.  You should use `America/Los_Angeles`.  It's in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Date` object stores time in milliseconds since the Unix epoch (without leap seconds).  This is the value you see when you call `.getTime()` or `.valueOf()`.  That is a purely UTC-based value, without any time zone.

Any string representation is the result of calls to `toString`, `toISOString`, etc. or implicit string conversion that occurs when logging to the debug console.

The implementations of the console debug output can vary across environments.  Some will show a string in local time (Chrome, IE, Edge), and some will show a string in UTC (Node, FF).

If you want to see the local date/time in Node/FF without any libraries, call `new Date().toString()`.  The output will be in local time.